# asp.net api return json from MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, json, mongodb, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return a document from MongoDB. I would prefer not to create a model due to the amount of fields in each document. This is what my current output looks like:

```
"[{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5bacec90075c4c53a8274135\"), \"lenders\" : { \"ZU10lldsmjbhmvd_39zrd\" : { \"companyName\" : \"....
```

The returned value appears to be serialized twice?  I want the output to be similar to this:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5bacec90075c4c53a8274135"),"lenders":{"ZU10lldsmjbhmvd_39zrd":{"companyName":"...
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] RequestInput input)
    {
        mongoDatabase = GetMongoDatabase();

        //Build the condition  for value input
        var value = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("request.property.value", input.value);

        //fetch results using filter from Test_Collection 
        var results = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Test_Collection").Find(value).ToList();

        string final = results.ToJson();

        return final.ToString();
    }
```

Any insight or tips on how to fix this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try returning `Ok(result)` instead of `result.ToJson();`

Comment: It looks like you are using asp.net core, please consider using the tag asp.net-core for better distinction.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your current result is expected result.

For `var results = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Test_Collection").Find(value).ToList();`, it will return a list `Test_Collection` which will be serialized into an json array.

If you expected this return only one document, you should replace `.ToList()` with `.FirstOrDefault()`.